# How convert string to byte[]?

Tags: arduino

I have Arduino + Ethenet shield. I want to dynamically change the ip depending on that will come at the input com-port.

The main problem is - input string has a String type, and `Ethernet.begin` method accepts a byte array. In general, I can not understand how to convert this string correctly. Tried to make a bicycle(crutch) by moving the string in the char array, and then in the byte array. Did not work out. How convert string to byte[]?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
String readString;
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; //physical mac address
byte myserver[] = { 208, 104, 2, 86 }; // zoomkat web page server IP address
EthernetClient client;

void initEthernetConfig(byte ip[])
{

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  Serial.println("Better client test 12/01/11"); // so I can keep track of what is loaded
  Serial.println("Send an e in serial monitor to test"); // what to do to test
}

void setup(){
  byte ip[] = { 10, 28, 33, 4 };
 // initEthernetConfig(ip);
}

void loop(){
  // check for serial input

   while (Serial.available()) {
    char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
    readString += c; //makes the String readString
    delay(2);  //slow looping to allow buffer to fill with next character
  }

  if (readString.length() >0) {
  byte inArray[4];
  char * tokens;
    int i = 0;    
    tokens = strtok(readString, ".");
    while (tokens != NULL) {
        inArray[i] = atoi(tokens);
        tokens = strtok(NULL, ".");
        i++;
    }
  initEthernetConfig(inArray);
  }

}
```

Comment: what is the point of `inArray` it is not used? How about casting to a byte
`inArray[i++] = (byte) atoi(tokens);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution, it parses, dumps and sets an *IPv4*:

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; //physical mac address
byte myserver[] = { 208, 104, 2, 86 }; // zoomkat web page server IP address
EthernetClient client;

/**
 * help functions declaration
 */

void get_ip(byte ip[4]);
void dump_ip(byte ip[4]);
void initEthernetConfig(byte ip[]);

/**
 * setup && loop
 */

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{
  byte ip[4];

  get_ip(ip);
  dump_ip(ip);

  initEthernetConfig(ip);
}

/**
 * help function implementation
 */

void get_ip(byte ip[4])
{
  for (byte i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    while (Serial.available() <= 0) { };
    ip[i] = (byte) Serial.parseInt();
    if (i < 3) { Serial.read(); } // throw away dot
  }
};

void dump_ip(byte ip[4]) {
  for (byte i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    Serial.print(ip[i]);
    if (i < 3) {
      Serial.print('.');
    } else {
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
};

void initEthernetConfig(byte ip[])
{
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Serial.println("Better client test 12/01/11"); // so I can keep track of what is loaded
  Serial.println("Send an e in serial monitor to test"); // what to do to test
};
```

---

Obviously, outside this testing application you should ensure that the `Serial` input is ready for sending an `IPv4` in the first place, otherwise the function will likely return `0.0.0.0`. An idea would be to enrich your communication protocol with *string-based* commands, e.g. `ip:` would signal the start of an `IPv4` input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while (tokens != NULL) {
    inArray[i++] = atoi(tokens) & 0xFF;
    tokens = strtok(NULL, ".");
}
```

Which will get only the last byte of the integer, but that is all you want in the case of values 0-255.

But then again why not just read it in as bytes...

```
void loop(){
  byte inArray[4];
  int i = 0;
  // check for serial input

   while (Serial.available()) {
    inArray[i++] = (byte) Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
    delay(2);  //slow looping to allow buffer to fill with next character
  }
  initEthernetConfig(inArray);
}
```